# Duplicate Search Engine results on Pythonanywhere

Tags: search-engine, sitemap, pythonanywhere

I am currently using my own domain name for my Pythonanywhere app. The original username.pythonanywhere.com still serves the same content as www.my-domain.com, and I wanted to know if there would be duplicate search engine results from this.

My sitemap.xml file is written for www.my-domain.com in case that changes anything. I only want www.my-domain to be crawled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is certainly possible. But would only realistically happen if you have people linking to your .pythonanywhere.com. We are currently working on a major upgrade that will give each webapp it's own wsgi server and the potential for this to occur will go away completely